# Change text from a FTP server to string (Python)

Tags: python, ftp

I would like to open [this site](ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/SymbolDirectory/otherlisted.txt) with Python and convert it to a string. I want the text to stay as it is because I am going to extract the first word of each line later. Here's what I tried:

```
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP('ftp.nasdaqtrader.com')
ftp.login()
a=ftp.retrbinary('NLST /SymbolDirectory/nasdaqlisted.txt', str)

print(a)
```

After this I get the following message

```
226 Transfer complete.
```

I would like to get the contents of the text file, not this. How do I fix it?

Comment: and what do you get ? Do you get error message ? Then add it in question. Don't expect that we will run code to see your problem.

Comment: Right, already did it @furas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: you have to use `RETR` instead `NLST`.

Second: retrieved data is send to function which you add in `retrbinary` as second argument.

Third: you may have to convert `bytes` to `string` using `decode()` (or `decode("UTF-8")` or `decode("some_encodig_name")`)

```
from ftplib import FTP

def my_function(data):
    print(data.decode())

ftp = FTP('ftp.nasdaqtrader.com')
ftp.login()
status = ftp.retrbinary('RETR /SymbolDirectory/nasdaqlisted.txt', my_function)

print(status)
```

Doc: [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ftplib.html), [standard-encodings](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)